# Stop Spring writing startup text to console (or anywhere)

Tags: java, spring

I have a simple console application that uses Spring for DI. When the application starts, spring dumps the following text to the console:

```
May 22, 2014 10:46:30 PM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext prepareRefresh
INFO: Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@4bb2668f: startup date [Thu May 22 22:46:30 EST 2014]; root of context hierarchy
May 22, 2014 10:46:30 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader loadBeanDefinitions
INFO: Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [spring-config.xml]
```

Does anyone know how to stop it writing to the console, and anywhere else? I want it to start silently.

Update:
Though this has been marked as a duplicate, the other question doesn't answer my question. That said, it would appear that what I want can't be achieved, so fair enough :)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see that one when I looked before.

Comment: If the other question does not resolve your issue, you should explain why, otherwose the question is likely to remain closed as duplicate.

Comment: Like I said, it would appear what I want can't be achieved.

Comment: Oh I see. Well, in my mind "it is not possible" is a valid answer, that's wy I didn't get it when you said "it does not answer".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `Log4j` for logging, then you can

```
log4j.logger.org.springframework = ERROR
```

this will disable the logs lesser than `ERROR` level

Comment: I don't have logging at all. I just want to stop Spring writing to the console.

Comment: Spring uses commons-logging. AFAIK, You need to instruct it to use Log4j instead and thus, stopping the spring classes logs.

Comment: Oh ok. I was hoping there was a property I could set. Wishful thinking. I'll leave it a few hours and if no-one else comments I'll mark your answer as **the** answer.